# How to draw a map of postal codes of a country?

Tags: cartography, postal-code

I have data:

<kbd>**postal code**</kbd><kbd>**value**</kbd>
<kbd>00-002</kbd>          <kbd>50</kbd>      
<kbd>00-003</kbd>          <kbd>70</kbd>      
...
<kbd>99-440</kbd>          <kbd>510</kbd>

where postal code is a postal code in Poland, and value is a number (it can be number of people, density, temperature etc.).
I want to create a map for this data. So I need a map with areas coloured depending of a value. Something like this [here](http://mapa-kodow-pocztowych.pl/). So such data exists somewhere.

- How can I get data that I can use to draw the map of Poland divided into areas with their postal code? Where can I find it?
- What software can I use to do this?
- If this is not a proper place for such question, where can I ask?

Comment: welcome to GIS SE. Could you please be more specific about the type of map that you want : is if for printing or for displaying on the Web ? Also, do you have any constraints on the use of a software ? Basically all GIS software can do what you want, so the question is too broad. May I suggest that you try with QGIS software and edit your question if you have more specific problem ?

Comment: Just a digital map for viewing and analysing. Thank you for your suggestion about software. The main problem now is how to get this map. It looks like there is no such map under a free license and I have to order and pay for it.

Comment: have you looked at http://www.gadm.org/ ? but I am not sure that administrative boundaries will match your postal code. Anyway, in your case, it would be better to ask two questions: first, where to find the data (there is a "data" tag), second on how to use the data (after trying with, e.g. QGIS)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the same. Postal code boundaries are different than boundaries for cities/municipalities/counties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To create a map like that, you will need a country boundary map, a state boundary map. I believe you can find the data you want [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). Try to search within the website.

   If you are looking for more gis data of Poland or other countries, try to find them from institutional sites. Sometimes you need to request them by sending email to a certain organization. But the easiest way to search data is google key words.I did this by google "gis data Poland".
2. Because data above is in shapefile format, I would recommend you to use gis software that support this kind of format. QGIS and ArcGIS are both good choices. QGIS is a cross-platform free and open-source desktop GIS application that provides data viewing, editing, and analysis capabilities. ArcGIS costs you thousand bucks to buy license. But most educational institutions have bought it for students to use.
3. Once you have access the data, try to open it and see what is in attribute table. If you don't know how to do, go to Youtube to see some tutorial videos (QGIS,ArcGIS).

Comment: Poland, not Portland!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it clearly. You can download Poland gis data here: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata.